# Argument #5 ($port) must be of type ?int, string given - error when setting up a form on laravel 9

Tags: javascript, laravel, smtp, laravel-blade

I am relatively new to backend, so I've encountered an error and I have no idea where to even start.

Everything works totally fine locally, I receive the response email from the SMTP server, no problem. As soon as it goes live, when I click submit on my form, I get this error:

> XHRreload?k=6LffRmckAAAAAA8fhqt3YfyTgWOpGuYRrlxTdSKy  XHRform
> 2 requests
> 36.9 kB transferred
> {,…}
> exception: "TypeError"
> file:
> "/var/www/sites/fantasy-road/docs/releases/2023-02-09-23.37/vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Dsn.php"
> line: 28
> message:
> "Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Dsn::__construct(): Argument #5 ($port) must be of type ?int, string given, called in /var/www/sites/fantasy-road/docs/releases/2023-02-09-23.37/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailManager.php on line 174"
> trace:
> [{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…]

I'm at a loss as how to even begin debugging this, and I have no idea what files to provide to give further insight as to what is causing the issue.

The last file I edited was my `FormController`:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Enquiry;

use Request;
use Redirect;
use Validator;
use App\Form;
use Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class FormController extends Controller {
    const contact_gallery_form_id = 7;

    public function submit() {
        $input = Request::all();

        $form_id = $input['_form_id'];

        $form = Form::where('id', $form_id)->first();

        if($form === null){
            \Log::error('Form doesn\'t exist');
            die("Form doesn't exist");
        }

        $return_url = config('forms.' . $form_id . '.return_url');
        $form_url = config('forms.' . $form_id . '.form_url');

        //my_time and my_name are honeypot fields
        unset($input['_token'], $input['_form_id']);

        $validator = Validator::make($input, config('forms.' . $form_id . '.validation'));

        unset($input['my_name'], $input['my_time'], $input['recaptcha_validation']);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            \Log::channel('warnings')->info('Invalid inputs for Form ID: ' . $form_id . '. Errors are : ' . $validator->errors());

            return abort(500, 'Invalid inputs: ' . $validator->errors());
        } else {
            if (\Request::has('file')) {
                $name = date("Ymd_His") . '_' . Str::slug(pathinfo(\Request::file('file')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME), '-') . '.' . \Request::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                \Request::file('file')->move(public_path() . '/assets/files/uploads/user', $name);
                $input['file'] = url('/assets/files/uploads/user/' . $name);
            }

            $email_content = '';
            $fields = ['publication-date_1', 'title_1', 'issue-number_1', 'value_1', 'publication-date_2', 'title_2', 'issue-number_2', 'value_2', 'publication-date_3', 'title_3', 'issue-number_3', 'value_3', 'publication-date_4', 'title_4', 'issue-number_4', 'value_4', 'publication-date_5', 'title_5', 'issue-number_5', 'value_5', 'publication-date_6', 'title_6', 'issue-number_6', 'value_6', 'publication-date_7', 'title_7', 'issue-number_7', 'value_7', 'publication-date_8', 'title_8', 'issue-number_8', 'value_8', 'publication-date_9', 'title_9', 'issue-number_9', 'value_9', 'publication-date_10', 'title_10', 'issue-number_10', 'value_10'];

            foreach ($input as $field_key => $field_val) {
                if (!in_array($field_key, $fields)) {
                    if($field_key == 'file'){
                        $email_content .= '
                            <br /><b>' . str_replace('_', ' ', ucfirst($field_key)) . ' :</b><br /><a href="' . $field_val . '">' . $field_val . '</a><br />';
                    } else {
                        $email_content .= '
                            <br /><b>' . str_replace('_', ' ', ucfirst($field_key)) . ' :</b><br />' . $field_val . '<br />';
                    }
                }
            }

            $email_content .= '
                <br /><b>Date :</b><br />' . date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . '<br />';


            $email_content .= '<table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Publication Date</th>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Issue Number</th>
                  <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>';

            for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
                $publication_date = $input['publication-date_' . $i] ?? '';
                $title = $input['title_' . $i] ?? '';
                $issue_number = $input['issue-number_' . $i] ?? '';
                $value = $input['value_' . $i] ?? '';

                if (!empty($publication_date) || !empty($title) || !empty($issue_number) || !empty($value)) {
                  $email_content .= '<tr>
                      <td>' . $publication_date . '</td>
                      <td>' . $title . '</td>
                      <td>' . $issue_number . '</td>
                      <td>' . $value . '</td>
                    </tr>';
                }
            }

            $email_content .= '</tbody></table>';

            $enquiry = new Enquiry();

            $encoded_post = json_encode($input);

            $enquiry->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $enquiry->post = $encoded_post;
            $enquiry->form_id = $form_id;
            $enquiry->save();

            if($form->id == static::contact_gallery_form_id){
                $gallery = \App\Gallery::findOrfail(\Request::get('contact_gallery'));
                $notification_emails = $gallery->email;
            } else {
                $notification_emails = $form->notification_emails;
            }

            $emails = explode(';', str_replace(' ' , '', $notification_emails));

            try {
                $data = array();
                $data['subject'] = 'Website form submission : ' . $form->name;
                $data['content'] = $email_content;
                $data['title'] = $form->name . ' Form Submission';

                if (isset($input['name']) && isset($input['email'])) {
                    $data['name'] = $input['name'];
                    $data['replyto'] = $input['email'];
                }

                foreach ($emails as $email) {
                    $data['notify'] = $email;

                    Mail::send('emails.form-notification', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
                        if(isset($data['replyto']) && isset($data['name'])){
                            $message->to($data['notify'])->replyTo($data['replyto'], $data['name'])->subject($data['subject']);
                        } else {
                            $message->to($data['notify'])->subject($data['subject']);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                \Log::error('Error sending start email | ' . $e . '');
            }

            return 'ok';
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any issues here that could cause this?

I have tried debugging the issue, but unable to locate the source.

Comment: What show this dd(env('MAIL_HOST')) ?

Comment: The error is saying that whatever port you have written to your config (maybe `.env` file), it is a `string` but the code is expecting nothing at all (`null`) or an `integer` value -> _"Argument #5 ($port) must be of type ?int, string given"_. So check where are you setting the port, `MAIL_PORT` or `MAIL_HOST`, also, just in case, check your `config/mail.php` port's default just in case (if you are not specifying your own port)

Comment: @matiaslauriti - 

I thought this was to case too, but I've already checked it:

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-relay.sendinblue.com
MAIL_PORT=587

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

My own stupidity was the cause of this issue.

As this was my first large scale project that I have worked on, on my own, doing both the rear and front end, I did not realise that the sensitive data was not pushed in the form of the .env

The cause of the issue was simple. The live .env file was empty, so to fix this I used SSH to get into the live files, and manually updated the .env (which you're supposed to do.) This fixed it.